# Amazon Web Service (AWS) S3, how to upload folder that is password protected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After looking over the GIT [repository](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Objective-C/) and reading the web interfacce [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/PuttingAnObjectInABucket.html), also had a look over this nice [tutorial](http://sledgedev.com/aws-s3-image-upload-using-aws-sdk-for-ios-v2/). I sow that it is possible to create a folder with some data(in this case an image) as:

```
...
_uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
....
_uploadRequest.key = @"foldername/image.png";
...
```

Now my question is hoe can I password protect the folder(Object as Amazon calls them)?

[I am asking because I sowed in the web interface that it specifies:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/PuttingAnObjectInABucket.html)

> When you add a file to Amazon S3, you have the option of including
>   metadata with the file and setting permissions to control access to
>   the file.

Comment: Do you want to password protect the folder or upload a password protected folder?

Comment: @error2007s I want to password protect a folder, also If I forget the password is there a way to reset it or something similar? (ps: thank you in advance)

Comment: Password protect a folder where in S3 or EC2 instance?

Comment: @error2007s in S3, on server side

Comment: You can password protect the Folder on the server but not on S3.

Comment: Is there anything similar to this on S3?

Comment: Nope you can only restrict the bucket access to public but no password protection.

Comment: Thank you @error2007s, can you formulate an official answer so I can up vote it?

Comment: Done My answer is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password protection for S3 Bucket is not available. If you want to secure the S3 bucket either you have to use Signed URLS to access the S3 resources or you can keep the S3 bucket private.